# Cannot save record/data to SQLite database with jdbc:sqlite::resource:

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I made a database with SQLITEStudio and saved it to my project folder.
The database name is ThirftersDataBase.db with table accHistory and columns "user" and "password".
The connection is working when I use a Select query but when I try to insert data, It doesn't work. Please help.

This is my database class.

```
package db.Util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class databaseConnection {

    static Connection con = getConnection();
    static String user;

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite::resource:ThirftersDataBase.db";
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("connected");
            return con;
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void logIN(String user, String pass) {

        String sql = "Insert or replace into accHistory(user, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement st;

        try {
            st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.setString(1, user);
            st.setString(2, pass);
            st.executeUpdate();


            //Check if query is executed;
            System.out.println("Saved");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And I have a FXML controller with a button that will save data when clicked.

```
public class ThriftersController{

    databaseConnection connect = new databaseConnection();

    public void Save(ActionEvent e) {
         //Save "Mark" to user column and save "1234456" to password column
        connect.logIN("Mark", "1234456");
    }
}
```

The button event is perfectly handled, when I click the button It will print "Saved" but doesn't save in my database.

Comment: `It doesn't work` ... is there any error output?

Comment: nothing.That's what I am confused and furious about. I'll try to copy other code and try if it works.

Comment: Is it possible that you have auto commit set to off?

Comment: It will be useful to have DDL of your accHistory table. You need to close statement and than connection: either use try with resources or try/finally block. Class name should start with uppercase letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database connections via `jdbc:sqlite::resource:` are read-only, as documented [here](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/wiki/Usage):

> **Reading Database Files in classpaths or network (read-only)**
>
> To load db files that can be found from the class loader (e.g., db files inside a jar file in the classpath), use `jdbc:sqlite::resource:` prefix.

You'll need to put your database in a different location if you want to update it.